# "Error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): The following query has been corrupted: ''

Tags: c#, ms-access-2016

This morning the program stopped running with this error message. Only works on my machine, everyone else. This program has been running for two years and no such bug has occurred so far. What could be the reason? Nothing has changed since last night.
I also reinstalled the ACCESS 2016 64x runtime, but unfortunately it did not improve.

This is a part of the update method:

```
string _AccessOperation_command = "UPDATE [" + targettables.Trim() + "] SET " + subcommandUpdatestring +
                                       " WHERE " + wherecondition.Trim();

    OleDbCommand update_dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(_AccessOperation_command, myConn);
    for (int i = 0; i < tombmeret; i++)
    {
       update_dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + targetField_intoValue[i, 0], targetField_intoValue[i, 1]);
    }

    try
    {
      var rowsAffected = update_dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      successUpdate = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
          _MasterErrorText = "Error: " + ex;
          successUpdate = false;
          return successUpdate;
        }

    return successUpdate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug, unfortunately I need to uninstall the latest Office ACCESS2016 security update. only this will solve it.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue popped up this morning in my access app which has prerviously always worked fine. Could you be a bit more specific about what update you removed to restore functionality, and how you removed it? Thankyou.