# Microsoft Access Query '' is Corrupt

Tags: ms-access

Thanks to a November 2019 Microsoft update, update queries on Access tables with where clauses are now generating the error, Query '' is corrupt.

See [Access error: "Query is corrupt"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-error-query-is-corrupt-fad205a5-9fd4-49f1-be83-f21636caedec) for details.

For my users, waiting nearly a month till December 10 for a fix release is not an option.  Nor is uninstalling the offending Microsoft update across government-controlled workstations as suggested in the related (not duplicate) Stack Overflow link [Getting Error 3340 Query ' ' is corrupt while executing queries DoCmd.RunSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832269/getting-error-3340-query-is-corrupt-while-executing-queries-docmd-runsql)

I will need to apply a workaround, but am not exactly thrilled with what Microsoft suggested - creating and substituting a query for each table.

The following works and does not require creating and saving a ton of additional queries.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Field1 = "x" WHERE (Field2=1);  'Generates error
```

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM Table1) SET Field1 = "x" WHERE (Field2=1);  'No error
```

That should be much easier to implement across several databases and applications (and later rollback).  If there is a simpler, better solution, please let me know.