# Why is the upd null sick query no longer working?

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a database that has been in use for many years. It was upgraded to .accdb back in 2010. It is currently being accessed using Access for Office 365 on a Windows 10 Pro computer. The database is stored on a network drive.

Everything has been working fine until today. Today I'm getting an error that the query [query name] is corrupt. I created a new query that does the same thing as the old one and am getting the same error message on the new query. I've added the database location to the trusted location, but that hasn't fixed the error.

The query in question is a simple update query.
It looks at one value in one table. 
Sets it to 0 if the current value is null.

Any ideas where I should look next?

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Can we see the query in question, as well as the error message, please? You can edit your question and copy-paste them both into the body of your question. Another thing I would check for is whether Access has been updated or upgraded lately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Error 3340 Query ' ' is corrupt while executing queries DoCmd.RunSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832269/getting-error-3340-query-is-corrupt-while-executing-queries-docmd-runsql)

Comment: @HansUp, that may, indeed, answer the question. I will let you know.

Comment: @HansUp, that did answer my question. I installed the update and the query started working fine again. Thank you!