# Excel VBA error "Query ' ' is corrupt" while executing update query using ADODB.Connection & Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have an update query in Excel 2013 vba.
Till recently it worked.
Now I got the error "Query ' ' is corrupt" in the "adoConn1.Execute" command.
I know there is an [Access Issue](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-error-query-is-corrupt-fad205a5-9fd4-49f1-be83-f21636caedec) caused by November Office update.
The problem is that I got the error in Excel and the problematic Office updates
where not installed in my PC. 
Can you help me?

```
strUpdateQuery= "Update [Table$] " & " SET FieldName = " & FieldValue

sConn1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & PathDB & "\" & FileNameDB & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"""

Set adoConn1 = New ADODB.Connection
adoConn1.Open sConn1
adoConn1.Execute strUpdateQuery, flagUpdateResult, adExecuteNoRecords

adoConn1.Close
If Not adoConn1 Is Nothing Then Set adoConn1 = Nothing
```

Comment: You are still using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 which is Access. Have you gone through https://stackoverflow.com/q/58832269/11683?

Comment: It did not help me. I searched "KB4484119" in order to uninstall it but did not find it. I didn't find any recent update relevant to Office. I keep getting this error in Excel.

Comment: The error number  is 2147467259 (800040005)

Comment: Have you tried the suggested workarounds?

Comment: You mean replace: Update TableName .... with "Update (SELECT * FROM TableName"?. I will try it.