# Microsoft Access Query is Corrupt after latest patch

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Due to an update Microsoft Access is erroring out on Query is Corrupt.

See question [Getting Error 3340 Query ' ' is corrupt while executing queries DoCmd.RunSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58832269/8053928)

I applied the latest patch which is supposed to fix this issue, however I'm still getting this error.
I tried on Access 2013 MSI version and Access 2016 MSI version.

I also tried a clean install of an older Access 2016 MSI which never had the update applied. Still no results.

I cannot edit the database to update all tables as suggested, since I don't have access to the backend.

Are there other fixes?

Comment: Is the query being executed in the backend ? Have u updated the backend PC too?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the backend pc as well.

Comment: Since patch didn't work, did you try workaround described by Gustav answer in that thread?

Comment: I cannot edit the database to make that change.

Comment: @June7 I cannot edit the database to make that change.

Comment: Why can you not modify db? Other than removing the update, I don't know of any other fix if patch will not resolve.