# Query is Corrupt vb.net ms access - different question from the standard

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Please bear with me! None of the Office updates have fixed the old Nov 2019 bug:

[Access error: "Query is corrupt"](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/access-error-query-is-corrupt-fad205a5-9fd4-49f1-be83-f21636caedec)

I know there are solutions like:

Before:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Field1 = "x" WHERE (Field2=1);
```

After:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM Table1) SET Field1 = "x" WHERE (Field2=1);
```

but how do you solve this if you work through a datatable?

```
ssql = "SELECT * FROM tblProject"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(ssql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "UpdateCoverPage")

Dim cb2 As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

   fill datatable here with data to be updated into ms access

da.Update(ds, "UpdateCoverPage")
```

What is the right syntax?  I can't find anything online about this.

when I try to update office i get :
[image]

so --- strange goingons!!!!

Comment: Since the update statement will be auto-generated by `da.Update`, I don't think there's much you can do here. Anyway, this workaround shouldn't be *necessary*, since the bug [has been fixed for all version of MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58833831/87698). Which version of MS Access/Office do you use?

Comment: I have Office professional edition 2013 - when I tried to update the fixes i got the message that there are no products that are affected by the update (paraphrasing here!)  I wish it were so simple!!!

Comment: Hmmm... maybe VB.NET uses a different Access-DB driver. What bitness does your VB.NET project have? And what bitness does Office have? Are all available Windows Updates installed?

Comment: not sure what you mean by bitness.  32/64bit?  mine is 32 bit.  as far as I can tell windows is completely up to date

Comment: Yes, I mean 32/64 bit. What bitness does your VB.NET project have (see project settings)? And what bitness does Office have (see About)? Don't guess, look it up. :-) And what is your (exact) connection string? I'm trying to find out whether your VB.NET app perhaps uses a different Access DB driver than the one used by your Office installation (and, thus, does not get the updates). And another question: Are you *sure* that it is this bug? I.e., does a manual UPDATE statement in VB.NET yield this exact problem?

Comment: in the settings under "compile" prefer 32 bit is checked.  Access is 32 bit as well.  connectionstring is : Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= followed by location and filename.  I was using the same pc, the same software, the same connectionstring without any issues until that fateful november day in 2019...  I'm sure it is the same bug.

Comment: @svenliegeois Maybe your copy of Office 2013 hasn't updated completely - up-to-date version information is at [Update history for Office 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2013).